# Woocommerce downloadable link accessible on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-drive-api, digital-downloads

When downloading a woocommerce digital product using a mobile device, google drive link can be accessed since it asks whether you want to open the file using google drive app. Once it’s opened using the app, it allows you to copy the download link. Is there any way to avoid the link from being accessed?

I hope I’ve made my case clear.

Comment: create two "links" one for desktop and one for mobile ?

Comment: How do you suggest I do that? I uploaded the downloadable files to the google drive and removed the restrictions to allow it to be downloaded by anyone. Then copied the link and made the link a direct downloadable link. My concern is that this would happen to the products I'm intending to sell.Here is a link to one of the products: https://vectors4u.com/product/mens-casual-wear-t-shirt-mockup/

Comment: without investment u wont get any good results. There are many platforms offering to protect your content and generate unique link everytime someone downloads. The link also expires after N time so you are somewhat in safe. Also protecting downloadable content is like fighting water... if someone wants to share it will do it. Accept it.

Comment: Any such platform you would like to suggest?